# Converting PI digits into text strings

Tags: ascii, analytics, pi

It's kind of interesting that pi's decimal representation never ends and never settles into a permanent repeating pattern. Meaning it's highly possible that pi contains every possible combination of numbers.

This guy calculated 5 trillions 5x(10^12) numbers of pi :D 
http://www.numberworld.org/misc_runs/pi-5t/details.html

From the internet: "Converted into ASCII text, somewhere in that infinite string of digits is the name of every person you will ever love, the date, time and manner of your death, and the answers to all the great questions of the universe."

Wondering if somebody has already converted and analyzed the resulting string for known sequences of letters (words/sentences)?

Comment: Consider reading http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/216343/does-pi-contain-all-possible-number-combinations/

Comment: I meant to ask if somebody did the conversion of (at least 1GB) pi numbers and analyzed it. (Took a word from dictionary and tried to find it in resulting string)

Comment: That's a waste of time.

Comment: You can easily figure out whether or not you're likely to find an X-letter word in N digits of Pi. Of course that depends heavily on the encoding and such...

Comment: I feel skeptical. I don't think that there is a decent phrase (not event a sentence) in those 5 trillions numbers converted into text :)

Comment: [Related](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bible_code)

Answer (score 5):

Check out this page: http://pi.nersc.gov/.

It allows you to search for both character strings and hexadecimal sequences. Note that this search engine only has indexed the first 4 billion decimals of pi, and uses a formula for arbitrarily positioned binary or hexadecimal digits after those indexed.

Comment: Cool! Didnt know tis exists. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

The idea that Pi contains everything ever is a nice idea, but if it's correct, that means there is also an infinite amount of false things about everything ever.  For example, if Pi contains a list of all the people you will ever love, then it will also have a list of people that seems that it is a list of people you will love, but in reality it's just a mix of names in a pattern that makes it look legit.

Following the same idea, the date, time, and manner of your death could also be "falsified".  For example, let's say you are a man named Jason Delara, and you die at the age of 83 at 11:35 PM in your sleep.  In Pi somewhere it can say in ASCII text "Jason Delara will die at age 83, 11:35 PM, passed in his sleep."  It would also say somewhere else that "Jason Delara will die at age 35, at 6:00 AM, passed in a car accident."  There could be an "infinite" amount of these false predictions.

There's also the fact that, if following the idea from above, all but one the answers to one of the great questions of the universe in that digit are wrong, even if many of the answers make sense.  I've thought about this a lot, and I thought "What if there's part of the digit that states which facts are correct and which are not?"  The answer is "Then there is an infinite amount of false lists in the digit claiming to do the same as the real list."  In short, it would be pointless to convert Pi to ASCII text to try and figure everything out.

I know I'm a little late the party, but I wrote this for anybody who comes here looking for the answers to the universe in an endless, non-repeating decimal.

Answer (score 2):

It is massively convenient that pi is an irrational number we're still finding digits for as if you can't find what you want in the sequence then by definition it just happens to be later on.

As for it containing hidden information - if you create any random sequence long enough, you'll be able to create simple words from the resulting output.

Conspiracy theorists just love to see patterns where there are none. They forget the other noise and are endlessly fascinated by mere coincidences.

Answer (score 0):

Would just like to provide further context this question. Yes, the point is that PI goes on infinitely. That means there are endless possibilities for sentence structure and letter combination. This means every single combination of letters will happen and is happening in PI. So technically, everything in PI could apply to everything in the observable world around us.